# Why the PHP curl is not working? When it works from command line curl?

Tags: php, curl, centos

When i do it from command line as below it works:

```
$ curl -X "POST" "https://ABCD/login/oauth2/access_token"  -H "Authorization: Basic XXXX="  -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  --data-urlencode "realm=XXX"  --data-urlencode "XXX=XXX"
```

But when i do it from PHP its not working:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ABCD/login/oauth2/access_token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$ss = array(
  'realm' => 'XXX',
  'XXX'=>'XXX'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($ss));    

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
array(
  'Authorization: Basic XXXX=',
  'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',     
));

$result=curl_exec ($ch);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Any idea what is that i am doing wrong? I get HTTP status that "Required parameters or body is missing or incorrect."

Comment: Use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` and compare PHP output with `curl -v` output to verify if you send exactly same headers and payload.

Comment: It is still not working. I tried all the way. Only the curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) is working via command line. But PHP curl is failing yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your command line says `--data-urlencode` — URL encoding

Your PHP says `'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',` — so you *say* you are URL encoding the data

It also says `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($ss));` — so you are **JSON encoding** it and not URL encoding it.

Send the URL encoded data you claim to be sending.

Comment: When i send the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ABCD/login/oauth2/access_token?realm=XXX&XXX=XXX');` by removing `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($ss));` it now reports HTTP error 500 `An internal server error occurred.

`

Comment: @YumYumYum — Why did you put the data in the query string instead of in the request body?

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'realm=XXX&XXX=XXX');` - when i send it like this now it still failing.

Comment: Why it is not working still? is it a BUG in PHP 5.4.16 on my CentOS 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64? (where curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) in command line works)